# Handling logger errors in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, error-handling

I am using the logger class to log some values. What I can't find any info on is how to handle errors from the logger itself. What are the errors that can be thrown and how do I handle them?

For example, if I try to log a line and the file is deleted externally or locked or some other issue preventing normal operation, how do I detect it and have a function run the init of my   logger class so it re-creates and re-configures it as if the class was freshly started? Normally I would try something like this but I can't find any reference to anything similar:

```
try:
    self.log.info('%s:%s:%s:%s', val1, val2, val3, val4)
except: IOError (or something like that)
     self.initializeLoggerFunct()
     # attempt to log again
```

Answer (score -1):

All exception are listed here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html
A little tutorial: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Exceptions

Comment: Yes, but which of those exceptions apply to logger class? There is no reference to logger on that page. Also logger does not throw exception the normal way, they are silenced by default if I am not mistaken.